# How to allow change Close Date on Opportunity irrespective of all Validation Rules

Tags: validation-rule, closedate

How do I allow users to change Close Date on Opportunity even if there are Validation Rules that ask them to fill certain fields, that cant be blank based on the Opportunity Stage they are in.I want to allow bypass those Validation Rules and irrespective of them allow to change Close Date.

Comment: Did you try adding NOT(ISCHANGED(CloseDate)) to the existing validation rules so these wont fire when changing Close Date

Comment: Is there another way, we have a lot of Validation Rules for Opportunities

Comment: I hope there wont be any other way because the existing validation rules should not get fired which means we may need to edit them I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `NOT(ISCHANGED(CLOSEDATE)`) in the validation rules so the validation rule won't get fired when changing the CloseDate field on opportunity. You may need to edit all the validation rules I guess as No validation rule should get fired when the closeDate is changed.